# Lambda function running on localstack Testcontainers not able to connect to redis Testcontainers

Tags: aws-lambda, redis, testcontainers, localstack

I am writing integration tests for AWS lambda function that is invoked with KinesisEvent and then writes some data to Redis and Kafka.
I am using LocalStack and Testcontainers to achieve the same.

I have tested the code with docker-compose.yml, and it works fine. But something goes wrong in Java tests.

Here are my container settings -

```
@ClassRule
  public static final LocalStackContainer localstack =
      new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
          .withEnv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", US_EAST_1.getName())
              .withNetwork(lambdaNetwork)
          .withServices(Service.KINESIS, Service.LAMBDA);

  @ClassRule
  public static final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer =
      new KafkaContainer(kafkaImage).withNetwork(lambdaNetwork).withExposedPorts(9093);

    redisContainer = new GenericContainer<>(redisImage).withNetwork(lambdaNetwork).withExposedPorts(6379);
    redisContainer.start();

    String redisHost = redisContainer.getHost();
    Integer redisPort = redisContainer.getFirstMappedPort();
```

When I put record on kinesis, lambda is invoked successfully, however I get following exception -

```
2023-08-24T18:41:03.309  WARN --- [   asgi_gw_1] l.s.a.i.executor_endpoint  : Execution environment startup failed: {"errorMessage":"Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name.","errorType":"redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException"}
```

I am also setting up network for containers. Can someone point out what could I be missing?

Comment: if you're using Localstack 2.0+ I think by default they spin lambdas as independent containers, and I don't know if they inherit all the networks Localstack is in.

Answer (score 0):

Having the following definition will allow to have the three containers use the same network

- Postgres container
- LocalStack container
- Lambda container created by LocalStack

```java
static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15-alpine")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("postgres");

    @Container
    static LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:2.2.0"))
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withEnv("LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK", ((Network.NetworkImpl)network).getName())
            .withNetworkAliases("localstack");
```

the key part is `.withEnv("LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK", ((Network.NetworkImpl)network).getName())` in `LocalStackContainer`

Take into account to use the following information to connect from the lambda to postgres (in this example)

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test
username=test
password=test
```

Network alias `postgres` was declared in `PostgresContainer`, so it should be used by the lambda in order to connect through the docker network.

Comment: Thanks for the insights Eddu. Adding these values definitely helped, but did not solve the issue for me.

Comment: can you share a minimal sample to reproduce it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eddu! His piece along with port mappings helped.

```
List<String> portBindings = new ArrayList<>(); portBindings.add("6379:6379"); // hostPort:containerPort 
redisContainer =
        new GenericContainer<>(redisImage)
            .withNetwork(lambdaNetwork)
            .withNetworkMode(lambdaNetwork.getId())
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(
                new Consumer<CreateContainerCmd>() {
                  @Override
                  public void accept(CreateContainerCmd createContainerCmd) {
                    createContainerCmd.withHostName("cache");
                    createContainerCmd.withName("cache");
                  }
                })
            .withExtraHost("host.docker.internal", "host-gateway")
            .withCommand("redis-server", "--save", "20", "1", "--loglevel", "warning")
            .withNetworkAliases("cache")
            .withExposedPorts(6379);
redisContainer.setPortBindings(portBindings);
redisContainer.start();
```